# Page request form dropdownlist all items

Tags: c#, asp.net

how do I get all Items of dropdownlists from page.request.form?

```
Page.Request.Form[dropdownlist1.UniqueID]
```

I add options to dropdownlist at javascript. so nothing returns from `dropdownlist1.Items`,

Thats why I am trying to get from `Page.Request.Form`

Answer (score 0):

try putting them in a Session like this :
**

- OnThePageLoad :

**

```
Session["dropdownitems"]=dropdownlist1.Items;
```

**

- When you want to get the value:

**

```
List <ListControl> items = Session["dropdownitems"];
```

you can use a for loop to manipulate the items in the variable items
PS : **NOT tested** , becouse i cant right now sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

I manage to work it like this;

```
<script>
        function ddlSectionToHidden() {
            var items = [];

            $('#<%= ddlSelecteds.ClientID %> option').each(function () {
                items.push($(this).val());
            });

            $('#<%= hfSelecteds.ClientID %>').val(JSON.stringify(items));
        }
</script>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfSelecteds" runat="server" />
```

link button >  `OnClientClick="ddlSectionToHidden()"`

Code Behind >

```
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Guid> Selecteds = serializer.Deserialize<List<Guid>>(hfSelecteds.Value);
```